# How do I get Kuwait Embassy Attestation in India?

Tags: immigration

I am looking for business opportunities in Kuwait, I am from India. I heard that if I want to go to Kuwait, I have to complete the Kuwait Embassy Attestation process in India. So can anyone guide me through the procedure?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The title suggests you want to obtain from the Kuwaiti Embassy in India a document called an "Embassy Attestation." The body, on the other hand, says you want to go to Kuwait, which requires a visa. Which do you wish to do?

Answer (score 1):

The Kuwait Attestation is needed to verify the genuineness of the document in case one wishes to use his personal, educational or commercial documents in Kuwait. Kuwait is one of the well-known countries to welcome immigrants to stay, work or do business in. Certificate Attestation for Kuwait is an important procedure that is to be followed mostly when you are planning to visit Kuwait.

**Kuwait Attestation**
The process to attest documents from the approved department is known as Certificate Attestation. To recognize the trustworthiness of documents, it is necessary to get an essential seal or signature from the authorized department on your document. There are more than one department and rules present in this process. Each of these authorities gives a stamp of their own on the backside of the document.

**Procedure for Kuwait Attestation**

Regional Level
It is the primary level of the document verifying process. This step of confirmation can be done by the notary or the University from where the certificates were issued, as per the requirement or from the Chamber of commerce in the case of commercial documents.

State Government
The verification of certificates from the state is carried out by three various companies as per the requirement of the document type. These companies are the State Home Department, Human Resource Department, and the Sub-Divisional Magistrate. SDM is independent of the state government, yet, the attestation performed by this authority is considered on the state level.

MEA Stamp
Ministry of External Affairs is the least level of authentication from the home government after which an MEA sticker is applied to the document. MEA is the central organization that deals with the foreign matters of the nation.

**Kuwait Embassy Attestation**
It is performed by the administrators of the Kuwait Embassy or consulate to attest the verified certificates. It is the last step in getting certificate attestation for Kuwait after the Ministry of External Affairs stamp.
Usually, the attestation of certificates can turn out to exhausting to be taken place individually. Assistance from specialists can confirm to be very useful. There are certificate attestation services that help in making the method easier for others.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, are you connected to the company you linked to? It's fine if you are but you're supposed to disclose the connection--you've used them, you work for them, or you're the owner.